# React rails rendering home page view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios, rack-cors

I have rails API and react separate app. I can fetch data from rails view homepage in the console. how do I render it using react? My react code is as follows:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios'

    class HomePage extends Component {

      componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/')
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <h1>{this.response}</h1>
        )
      }
    }

export default HomePage
```

[image: Console react page fetching data from rails api running on localhost:3001]

Answer (score 0):

You could store the response in `state` e.g. as `data` and then render `this.state.data`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `response` globally if you want to call it like that in your render. The way you have it now, `this.response` isn't attached to anything. Colin hit the nail on the head -

```
class HomePage extends Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          heading: ''
        }
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/')
        .then(function (response) {
          this.setState({
            heading: response.data
          })
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }

      render(){
        return(
          <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
        )
      }
    }
```